# tic tac toe using alpha beta prunning in java

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, evaluation, tic-tac-toe

I am trying to play tic tac toe using iterative Alpha-Beta prunning,
I have one second limit for a move but for some reason it
doesnt work well.

I modified the regular alpha-beta code so instead of returning
alpha or beta, it returns a state (which is the board with the next move)

Each time I create children I update their depth.

But again for some reason I keep losing and I see that
my alpha beta doesnt see the best move to make.

Here is my code:

The outer loop:

```
while (watch.get_ElapsedMilliseconds() < 900 && d <= board.length * board[0].length - 1)
        {
            s = maxiMin(beginSt, d, watch);
            if (s.getNextMove().getIsWin() == true)
            {
                break;
            }
            d++;
        }
        return new location(s.getNextMove().getRow(), s.getNextMove().getCol());
```

The alpha beta:

```
public State maxiMin(State s, int depth, Stopwatch timer)
    {
        if (s.getDepth() == 7)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        if (timer.get_ElapsedMilliseconds() > 850 || s.getDepth() == depth || goalTest(s.getBoard()) != 0)
        {
            s.evaluationFunc(line_length, PlayerShape);
            s.setAlpha(s.getEvaluation());
            s.setBeta(s.getEvaluation());
            return s;
        }
        LinkedList<State> children = createChildren(s, true);
        // No winner, the board is full
        if (children.get_Count() == 0)
        {
            s.evaluationFunc(line_length, PlayerShape);
            s.setAlpha(s.getEvaluation());
            s.setBeta(s.getEvaluation());
            return s;
        }
        while (children.get_Count() > 0)
        {
            State firstChild = children.get_First().get_Value();
            children.RemoveFirst();
            State tmp = miniMax(firstChild, depth, timer);
            int value = tmp.getBeta();
            if (value > s.getAlpha())
            {
                s.setAlpha(value);
                s.setNextMove(tmp);
            }
            if (s.getAlpha() >= s.getBeta())
            {
                return s;
            }
        }
        return s;
    }

    public State miniMax(State s, int depth, Stopwatch timer)
    {
        if (s.getDepth() == 7)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        if (timer.get_ElapsedMilliseconds() > 850 || s.getDepth() == depth || goalTest(s.getBoard()) != 0)
        {
            s.evaluationFunc(line_length, PlayerShape);
            s.setAlpha(s.getEvaluation());
            s.setBeta(s.getEvaluation());
            return s;
        }
        LinkedList<State> children = createChildren(s, false);
        // No winner, the board is full
        if (children.get_Count() == 0)
        {
            s.evaluationFunc(line_length, PlayerShape);
            s.setAlpha(s.getEvaluation());
            s.setBeta(s.getEvaluation());
            return s;
        }
        while (children.get_Count() > 0)
        {
            State firstChild = children.get_First().get_Value();
            children.RemoveFirst();
            State tmp = maxiMin(firstChild, depth, timer);
            int value = tmp.getAlpha();
            if (value < s.getBeta())
            {
                s.setBeta(value);
                s.setNextMove(tmp);
            }
            if (s.getAlpha() >= s.getBeta())
            {
                return s;
            }
        }
        return s;
    }
```

Would appriciate much if anyone can tell me if something is wrong. I suspect maybe
it something to do with that I am returning "s" instead of the regular alpha beta
which returns the evaluation but I didnt manage to find the error.

Thanks in advance,

Lena

Comment: I think you should start with Minimax (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) then when you get that working add in alpha beta. That will make it much easier to debug. Minimax is essentially alpha beta without the pruning. Minimax will easily solve tic tac toe in under a few seconds.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly tic-tac-toe is a very simple game, and I believe it is solvable with a much simpler code, mainly because we know there is always a tie option and the total number of states is less then 3^9 (including symmetrical and many impossible states).

As for your code I believe one of your problems is that you don't seem to increment your depth in the recursive calls.

you also have many issues of bad style in your code, you separated miniMax and MaxiMin into two functions though they are fundamentally the same. you iterate over a collection by removing elements from it as opposed to using for-each or an iterator(or even an int iterator).